# Change the color of the cv2.rectangle

Tags: python, opencv, colors

I'm trying to make a color detection system where when I click on the window it tells the color. I'm now trying to make the color of the `cv2.rectangle` to change the color to what color I click on.

This is what I have done so far

```
import cv2
import webcolors
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageTk
from tkinter import filedialog
import cv2
# --- functions ---

def closest_colour(requested_colour):
    global colorcode
    colorcode = requested_colour
    min_colours = {}
    for key, name in webcolors.css3_hex_to_names.items():
        r_c, g_c, b_c = webcolors.hex_to_rgb(key)
        rd = (r_c - requested_colour[0]) ** 2
        gd = (g_c - requested_colour[1]) ** 2
        bd = (b_c - requested_colour[2]) ** 2
        min_colours[(rd + gd + bd)] = name
    return min_colours[min(min_colours.keys())]

def get_colour_name(requested_colour):

    try:
        closest_name = actual_name = webcolors.rgb_to_name(requested_colour)
    except ValueError:
        closest_name = closest_colour(requested_colour)
        actual_name = ""
    return actual_name, closest_name

def click_event(event, x, y, flags, param):
    global closest_name, colour2 # inform function to assign to global/external variable instead of creating local one

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN:
        B, G, R = frame[x, y]
        colour2 = (R, G, B)  # reverse values
        colour = frame[y,x][::-1] # reverse values
        actual_name, closest_name = get_colour_name(colour)


font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX

closest_name = '' # create global variable at start
requested_colour = ''
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0);

cv2.namedWindow('frame')
cv2.setMouseCallback('frame', click_event)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if closest_name:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (600, 60), (0, 0), (224, 224, 224),cv2.FILLED)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), (colour2), -1)
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), (0, 0, 0), 2)

        cv2.putText(frame, closest_name, (110, 40), font, 1, (0, 0, 0), 1)


    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    cv2.resizeWindow('frame', 500, 450)

    if cv2.waitKey(40) == 27:
        break
```

This is the error I'm getting

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:/Users/Suhail
>   Misbah/PycharmProjects/Color_Detection/colordetection.py", line 70, in
>   
>       cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), (colour2), -1) TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)

Comment: I'm really encouraging you to go through the [python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/). You shouldn't use global variables the way you do, it just makes the code messy and difficult to read.

Answer (score 4):

The `color` parameter of the `cv2.rectangle` expects a tuple of 3 integer representing the three color components, RGB. By calling the function the following way :

```
colour2 = (R,G,B) 
cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), (colour2), -1)
```

you are passing to the function the following tuple : `((R,G,B))`, which is a tuple containing one element : a tuple. Use

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), colour2, -1)
```

instead.

**Update** : It seems that the color components returned by `frame[x,y]` are `numpy.uint8`. However, the `color` parameter of `cv2.rectangle` expects a python `int`. You need to convert your color component first, for example with :

```
cv2.rectangle(frame, (10, 10), (100, 50), (int(x) for x in colour2), -1)
```

Comment: Is it still the same Traceback ? If not consider asking another question, or following a tutorial.

Comment: how do i do that